# Does adding a preposition and a noun after an object of a comma-separated list of verbs add it to all the verbs or only the last one in the list?

Tags: meaning, grammar, prepositions, punctuation, commas

I have a sentence (which I came up with myself):

- *This is a program intended to help users create, simplify and organize learning content into bite-sized chunks.*

After taking a second look at it, I realized there are multiple ways to interpret this:

1. This is what I actually mean:

- *This is a program intended to help users create learning content, simplify learning content and organize learning content into bite-sized chunks.*

2. This is what I think it could also mean but don't want it to mean so and neither does it make perfect sense:

- *This is a program intended to help users create learning content into bite-sized chunks, simplify learning content into bite-sized chunks and organize learning content into bite-sized chunks.*

Should I reframe the sentence as:

> This is a program intended to help users create and simplify learning content and organize it into bite-sized chunks.

I would like to know the correct way to interpret the first sentence.

Comment: I would interpret your first sentence in the way you want it to be interpreted if only because the phrases  "create learning content into bite sized chunks" and "simplify learning content into bite sized chunks" don't make much sense. However "To help users create and simplify learning content and to help them organise it into bite sized chunks" would make it completely unambiguous.

Comment: Yes, the scope of the prepositional phrase includes all three verbs. I _would_ go with your final rewrite (I've made a correction) – adding 'then' makes 'organise it' sound less weak (repeating 'learning content' would be worse, adding clunkiness). But I've the semantic problem that 'organising into bite-sized chunks' is not distinct from 'simplifying'.